# Create responsive td colspan tables

Tags: responsive-design, html-table

I have been using the following row of code throughout hundreds of tables at my site. However I've now coded a lot of these tables to be more responsive, and to hide columns which are not essential on a mobile device.

```html
<tr>
  <td colspan="11" class="resultsubheading">Not Classified</td>
</tr>
<tr class="resulttext" onmouseover="this.className='cell_over';" onmouseout="this.className='cell_out';" unselectable="on">
  <td class="resultpos"></td>
  <td class="resultnum">74</td>
  <td class="resultclass"></td>
  <td class="resultdriver"><a href="../../../drivers/wtcc/oriola_results.php#2013">Pepe ORIOLA</a></td>
  <td class="resultnat"><img src="../../flag/es.gif" title="Spain"></td>
  <td class="resultentrant"><a href="../../../teams/wtcc/tuenti_results.php">Tuenti Racing Team</a></td>
  <td class="resultcar">SEAT Le&oacute;n WTCC</td>
  <td class="resultlaps">8</td>
  <td class="resulttime">DNF</td>
  <td class="resultbest">2:20.073</td>
  <td class="resultgd">4</td>
</tr>
```

The problem I'm having it that there is no way to define the colspan in CSS, which is what hides the other columns on a mobile device when not needed.

I've included an extra row, to show that each table cell has a class which is either hidden or unhidden depending on the screen width in the CSS stylesheet.

Is there a simple and effective way to define colspan, or equivalent, depending upon the screen width, like in CSS?

I have also created a fiddle to try to illustrate my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6g48/1/

Answer (score 2):

Ran into this problem and solved it by adding duplicate thead markup without the colspan and with the class 'mobile-head'.

Above 425px the mobile head is hidden, below it's shown with `display: table-header-group;` and the original thead is hidden.

```css
table thead.mobile-head{
  display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 425px){
    thead{display: none}
    table thead.mobile-head{
        display: table-header-group;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

```html
<thead>
  <tr data-hook="cart_items_headers">
    <th class="cart-item-description-header" colspan="2"><%= t('spree.item') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-price-header"><%= t('spree.price') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-quantity-header"><%= t('spree.qty') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-total-header"><%= t('spree.total') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-delete-header"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<thead class="mobile-head">
  <tr data-hook="cart_items_headers">
    <th class="cart-item-description-header"><%= t('spree.item') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-price-header"><%= t('spree.price') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-quantity-header"><%= t('spree.qty') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-total-header"><%= t('spree.total') %></th>
    <th class="cart-item-delete-header"></th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent article about data tables and responsive design. This is the link: http://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/ hope it helps!

Comment: Ultimately this isn't what I went with. I used something similar to my above example to simply choose which columns weren't as important on a small screen and hide them, whilst introducing a message that tells users if they want to view the full detailed information they need to view on a larger screen.